# How to retrive multiple entries associated with a primary key in a different MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables like so:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| PLACES                                            |
-----------------------------------------------------
| Id             | Name          | Address          |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1              | Parc          | 20 King St       |
| 2              | Bar           | 33 Main St       |
-----------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------
| PEOPLE                                            |
-----------------------------------------------------
| Id             | Place_id (fk) | Name             |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1              | 2             | Luke             |
| 2              | 1             | Han              |
| 3              | 1             | Chewie           |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to display every places with their associated people. To do so I though it would be great to have a single record per place with an list of people (instead of having the same place for each people entry).

I'm really not familiar with SQL queries so I tried using Right Join and Group By without any positive results.

```
SELECT plc.name, plc.address, plp.name 
        FROM places plc
            RIGHT JOIN people plp
                ON plp.place_id = plc.id
                    GROUP BY plc.name;
```

The results I got after doing "$query->fetchAll();" in PHP were something like that:

```
Object {name: "Bar", address: "33 Main St", name: "Luke"}
Object {name: "Parc", address: "20 King St", name: "Han"}
Object {name: "Parc", address: "20 King St", name: "Chewie"}
```

I guess the best solution possible would be to have something filtered like that, which would prevent additional work both from the backend and frontend side. However, I have **absolutely no idea if it's possible**:

```
Object {name: "Bar", address: "33 Main St", name: "Luke"}
Object {name: "Parc", address: "20 King St", name: ["Han", "Chewie"]}
```

Any advices or suggestions on how I could achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest way would be to use group_concat

```
select
  place.id as `Id`,
  place.address as `address`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(people.name) as `peopleList`
from
  place,
  peoples
where
  place.id=people.place_id
group by
  place.id
```

and, if you see your results getting cropped, you can increase the size limit of GROUP_CONCAT like this:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 8192;
```

Answer (score 1):

GROUP_CONCAT() function is used for this purpose.

Here is a query for you to test on your DB.

```
SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(pp.name) as people_list FROM places p inner join people pp on p.id = pp.place_id group by p.id;
```

Comment: even better to add order by in the GROUP_CONCAT as well.
GROUP_CONCAT(pp.name order by pp.name)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Name, a.Address, group_concat( b.Name ) AS pname FROM `places` AS a
LEFT JOIN `people` AS b ON a.Id = b.Place_id
GROUP BY a.Name
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't it be group by column id of table 'places' ?

Comment: yeah, that will be more faster(better), although giving the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Frank, I know a solution to accomplish your goals. You have your query, which returns results such as:

```
Object {name: "Bar", address: "33 Main St", name: "Luke"}
Object {name: "Parc", address: "20 King St", name: "Han"}
Object {name: "Parc", address: "20 King St", name: "Chewie"}
```

That's really nice, I would order them by name in your query just to make sure that your data is easy-to-parse:

```
SELECT plc.name, plc.address, plp.name 
        FROM places plc
            RIGHT JOIN people plp
                ON plp.place_id = plc.id
            order by plc.id
```

Notice I've excluded the group by clause.

Ok, now you can iterate through your set of objects, build up another set of objects which will have the structure you have described and voilá, you're ready to go.